# Error: JTable muestra columna vacía (DefaultTableCellRenderer) (getCurrencyInstance())

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

no encuentro la solución, el caso es que quiero cambiar los datos de una columna que existen por otro formato, en concreto... que me cambien datos decimales a moneda local en la columna 2 que es como lo tenia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora con es metodo:

```
NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();


public class CurrencyCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {




@Override
public final Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    final Component result = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
            isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    if (value instanceof Number) {
        setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
        setText(defaultFormat.format(value));
    } else {
        setText("");
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

```
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new CurrencyCellRenderer());
```

Me sale así (columna borrada):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que quiero es que me salga toda la columna con este formato(de moneda):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En espera de vuestra ayuda, Gracias!

[SOLUCIÓN] Esta es la solución:

```
public class MyRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int col) {
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer
                = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
        String s = "";
        if (col == 2) {
            double d = Double.parseDouble( String.valueOf(value)) ;
            s = defaultFormat.format(d);
            c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, s,
                    isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
            ((JLabel) c).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        }
        return c;
    }
}

jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new MyRenderer());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás seguro de que la variable `value` es un subtipo de `Number`?

Comment: Si te digo la verdad Betanzos... es que no tengo ni idea, hace poco que me he puesto a programar en java y no tengo ni idea, voy copiando y pegando y así me van las cosas :P

Comment: Pon un punto de ruptura en esta línea `if (value instanceof Number) {`, y ejecuta la aplicación en modo de depuración, para que puedas determinar si lo que llega en `value` es del tipo de dato que esperas.

Comment: He hecho lo que me has dicho, no sabia esto del Breakpoint, he visto que en value cuando pulso F5 va cambiando el valor, como recorriendo la columna de la tabla paso por paso.